# How to get first and last day in month view at DateTimePicker

Tags: c#, datetimepicker, weekday

I have a DataTimePicker in a Forms application. Is there an easy way (preferably in C#) to get the first and last shown day of a month. So for example for 1st of December I like to get the 24th of November 2014 and the 4th of January 2015 as shown in the picture.

[image: DateTimePicker Control]

Comment: Something like [DateTimePicker.MaxDate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.minimumdatetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: @Mihai, MaxDate does not help. MaxDate defines the "total" possible max date (default 9998-12-31).

Comment: @Wernfried have you tried anything?

Comment: @DevEstacion I tried like "go back to first day of current week, then `AddDays(7)` in a loop until next month is reached" But I am not fully satisfied yet. Perhaps sombody else had already the same issue and a well working tested solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it should be something like that (e.g. int year=2014; int month=12 for current month):

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(year, month, 1);
int offset = ((int)dt.DayOfWeek - (int)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek + 6) % 7 + 1;
DateTime firstDate = dt.AddDays(-offset);
DateTime lastDate = firstDate.AddDays(41);
```

You can see that DateTimePicker puts the first of month in the first line except it is the first day of week. Then the first of month is in the second line. Therefore you have to look at the cultural settings for first day of week.

Comment: I just checked DateTimePicker shows always 6 weeks (41 days) even when it is not needed, e.g. for February 2011 it would be sufficient to display only 5 weeks.

Comment: Yes and in some years 4 weeks would do it for February. I think for design reasons they always show the same number of weeks to avoid 'flattering' of the control when scrolling through the months.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another one I tried, It's working but i see that Fratyx already made an answer. So I'll just post it here.

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DateTime date = new DateTime(2014, 12, 1);
    var firstAndLastDays = getFirstDateInDatePicker(date);
}

private static Tuple<int, int> getFirstDateInDatePicker(DateTime date)
{
    int totalDaysInMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(date.Year, date.Month);
    int totalDiff = TOTAL_DAYS - totalDaysInMonth;
    DateTime firstDayOfMonth = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, 1);
    DateTime lastDayOfMonth = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, totalDaysInMonth);
    int subtractor = (6 + (int)firstDayOfMonth.DayOfWeek) * -1;
    return new Tuple<int, int>(firstDayOfMonth.AddDays(subtractor).Day,
        lastDayOfMonth.AddDays(totalDiff + subtractor).Day);
}
```